# React useReducer find and change single object in state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-hooks

I have a state object that contains an array inside names `rows`. This array contains a list of objects:

```
{_id: "5e88ad4c5f6f7388d50b9480",
stampa: "Confezione",
S: 0,
M: 0,
L: 0,
XL: 0,
coloured: "",
modello: "",
SKU: ""}
```

Now, in a form I dispatch an action that the payload contains exactly the same object, the only differences are the keys `S`, `M`, `L`, `XL` that can change.

Then, in my reducer, I want to find in my original state the same object by matching with `_id`, and then update it with the object that comes with the payload.
This is my attempt, however I am getting the following error:

`TypeError: state.rows.map is not a function`

```
case "UPDATE_ROW":
      return state.rows.map((row) =>
        row._id === action.payload._id
          ? {
              ...row,
              _id: action.payload,
            }
          : row
      );
```

How can I tackle this in a better way?

EDIT:
This is my reducer:

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_STATE":
      return {
        ...state,
        rows: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    case "UPDATE_ROW":
      console.log("updating", action.payload);
      return state.rows.map((row) =>
        row._id === action.payload._id
          ? {
              ...row,
              _id: action.payload,
            }
          : row
      );

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

And this is my state:

```
import React, { createContext, useReducer } from "react";
import AppReducer from "./AppReducer";

// Initial State
const initialState = {
  rows: [],
};

export const GlobalContext = createContext(initialState);

// Provider component
export const GlobalProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(AppReducer, initialState);
  console.log(state);

  return (
    <GlobalContext.Provider value={[state, dispatch]}>
      {children}
    </GlobalContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

Comment: Post your entire `useReducer` code.

Comment: Make sure that `state.rows` is an array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue you are having there is that you should default state.rows to be an array in order for the type error to stop.
Other than that, from what I see there, your logic seems fine.

EDIT:

Okay, looks like your issue was that you weren't returning the full state when you were running the "UPDATE_ROW" case. If you use this, I believe the issue should be fixed.

I also fixed the logic in the reducer case as well. It looked like you were adding the entirety of the payload object in the _id property while keeping the rest of the row the same. Rather than update the row with the payload property.

```
export default (state, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case "UPDATE_STATE":
      return {
        ...state,
        rows: action.payload,
      };
    case "SET_ERROR":
      return {
        ...state,
        error: action.payload,
      };
    case "UPDATE_ROW":
      console.log("updating", action.payload);
      return {...state, rows:state.rows.map((row) =>
        row._id === action.payload._id
          ? {
              ...action.payload
            }
          : row
      )};

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Comment: I've updated based on your code. I believe this should help now.

Comment: Thanks, that was the mistake! I wasn't returning the state!